# Strange behavior, POST adds brackets to int value

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, request

I'm trying to send a dict through a POST request where the keys are int's and the values are lists but when the dict is received on the server the int's have been converted to unicode and the keys have brackets on the end of them.

Dict before POST

```
{157: ['foo', 'bar'], 154: ['foo']}
```

Dict after POST

```
{'157[]': ['foo', 'bar'], '154[]': ['foo']}
```

ajax code

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: dict,
    ...
 });
```

How I receive the data

```
dict = request.POST
```

Then I loop over it with `dict.iteritems()`

Does anyone know why those brackets are there after the POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The representation of an array in a URL-encoded parameter uses `[]` after the parameter name. If you have a parameter like:

```
param: [ "value1", "value2", "value3" ]
```

it's encoded as:

```
param[]=value1&param[]=value2&param[]=value3
```

How this gets decoded on the server depends on the language and/or framework. PHP automatically removes the `[]` when it generates the keys for `$_POST` or `$_GET`. Apparently Python does not do this, so the dictionary keys have `[]` appended.

Comment: Thanks! Now I don't have to spend hours trying to find an "official" way of fixing this and can just go straight to removing the brackets manually.